# Rotate text 90° with the resulting div having position within parent

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-transforms

When I rotate text (or rather a div containing text) this results in the div ***escaping*** it's parent.
Not only that, but the height of the div is it's original width.
I'd rather just stick with CSS to get the desired result rather than relying on javascript/jquery even though those tools are available since I'm using Bootstrap-4
How can I make sure a rotated div stays inside it's parent, and use's it's parents' width/height as it's basis for height/width because of being rotated 90° ?

**THANKS!**

```css
.emptydropzone{
 height: 10vh;
 border: 1vh dashed #000; 
 border-radius: 1vh;
 background-color:  #CCC;
}

.taflag{
 width: 98%;
 min-height: 50px;
 margin: 10px 125px 10px 5px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 5px solid #90C;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color:  #90C;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size:xx-large;
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.rotateparent {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: yellow; /* this is just to see the parent div in testing */
}

.agentflag{
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 border: 5px solid #F00;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color:  #F00;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size:xx-large;
 font-weight: bolder;
 
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
                  <div class="taflag"> TA </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
                 <div class="emptydropzone" id="ta" > </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
                  <div class="rotateparent">
                       <div class="agentflag"> AGENTS </div>
                     </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-10">

   <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent1"> </div>
   <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent2"> </div>
   <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent3"> </div>
   <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent4"> </div>
                
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

writing-mode might be much more efficient here .

possible update with less html and more boostrap classes

```css
.emptydropzone {
  min-height: 10vh;
  border: 1vh dashed #000;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.taflag {
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 125px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 5px solid #90C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #90C;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.rotateparent {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.agentflag {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
  /* untill 
  writing-mode:sideways-lr; works everywhere */
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #F00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <div class="taflag"> TA </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <div class="emptydropzone" id="ta"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-2 d-flex rotateparent m-0">
            <div class="agentflag m-auto"> AGENTS </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column justify-content-around">

            <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent1"> </div>
            <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent2"> </div>
            <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent3"> </div>
            <div class="emptydropzone" id="agent4"> </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```